# How to get the total count for each distinct category

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, distinct

I would like to get non-repeating rows for locations and get the total count of players in specific clans and the total count of those who are star players. Please see below for more explanation

```
table p:
player_id    stars
1            10
2            10
3            10
4            10

table a:
player_id    location   clan
1               egate   dragons
2               ngate   sabrelights
3               sgate   dragons
4               wgate   tigers
5               lgate   fireflies
6               lgate   fireflies
7               egate   dragons
```

Here's what I tried

```
    SELECT DISTINCT (CASE SUBSTR (location, 1, 1)
              WHEN 'e' THEN 'East'
              WHEN 'n' THEN 'North'
              WHEN 's' THEN 'South'
              WHEN 'w' THEN 'West'
              WHEN 'l' THEN 'Limbo'
              ELSE null
          END) loc
        ,clan clans  
        , sum (case when a.player_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total
        ,sum (case when p.stars = '10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) stars                                                                                            
        FROM   a
             left outer join p on p.PLAYER_ID = a.player_id 
                   group by SUBSTR (location, 1, 1),a.clan, p.STARS
            ,clan
           order by loc, clans
```

actual results (wrong):

```
LOC     CLANS    TOTAL  STARS
East    dragons     1   0
East    dragons     1   1
South   dragons     1   1
Limbo   fireflies   2   0
North   sabrelights 1   1
West    tigers      1   1
```

what I want (desired output):

```
LOC     CLANS   TOTAL  STARS    
East    dragons     2   1
South   dragons     1   1
Limbo   fireflies   2   0
North   sabrelights 1   1
West    tigers      1   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `p.stars` from your GROUP BY clause

It is tripping things up because it is establishing another unnecessary subdivision of your groupings. It only appears inside an aggregate (SUM) function so it does not have to be present in the group by, and your `sum case when p.stars` is doing the correct job of counting where a player is star or not

If you want better visibility of why this caused a problem, put p.stars back in the group by and also as a column in the select - you'll see the grouping keys (columns that aren't an aggregate function) and it should become obvious why it caused the split rows to appear

If stars is an integer count of the number of stars a player has earned, you might want to make it a `>= 10` check - this is more robust than an equals check, just in case it ever goes higher (unless 11+ stars means the player is no longer a star player..). Also if a column is an int is should be compared with a constant int rather than a constant string (`10 rather than '10'`)

Comment: I added some additional advice and explanation

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I will play around with the code, very helpful indeed!